# How to include the symbol "{" in a Python format string?

Tags: python, string

How can I include { symbol in a string?

My string

```
str2="call_function(Macro, {0});\n \{ \t int n;\n".format("value")
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ValueError: unmatched '{' in format
```

I have escaped the  {  symbol and have tried without escaping too. I'm getting the same error in both cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces {}. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal text, which is copied unchanged to the output. **If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: {{ and }}**.  <sup>[docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)</sup>

---

```
In [1]: '{{{0}'.format('foo')
Out[1]: '{foo'
```

Comment: [If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: {{ and }}.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

Comment: Hey thanks for the useful tip. Works perfect. Any other escaping tricks that I need to know ?

Comment: @Abhishek -- [Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal text, which is copied unchanged to the output.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings). Anyway, I think it would be useful to chew yourself through the docs...

Answer (score 0):

also can do like this

```
'{%s' % 'foo'
```